# Custom Font Width Not Rendered Correctly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face, webfonts

On one of our websites, we use a font from typotheque.com by importing it as follows:

```
@import url( "http://fonts.typotheque.com/WF-XXXXX-XXXXX.css" );
```

The font is displayed correctly on Chrome and the like. In Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, the font is rendered, but the width of it is not correct. It seems as if the width of the text is rendered **before** the font is applied.

---

As a consequence, the text gets overlapped and the words are not wrapping accurately:

[image: not correct on Internet Explorer]

---

On Chrome, the font width is calculated and the words are wrapped correctly:

[image: displaying correctly on Chrome]

---

**Other things we tried:**

- We followed the instructions here on [typotheque.com](https://www.typotheque.com/webfonts/tutorial)
- We made sure to link the css files prior to the javascript files, [as stated here](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/#ieupdate).

Any hints or pushes in the right direction to solve this issue are much appreciated. You can find the website here: http://www.claireundgeorge.ch/fr/

**Edit:**

- Added `word-break: break-all;` : no change
- Removed all the font-awesome-stuff: no change

Comment: Did you use the rule - word-break: keep-all;

Comment: Yes, nothing changed

Comment: I looked at your stylesheet and you're loading a bunch of font-awesome stuff before you're loading the page styles. Try changing the order. Put your own page styles first, specifically the styles that apply your font.

Comment: Removed the font-awesome-stuff, but to no avail

Comment: And the rule word-break: keep-all;

Comment: I just checked the waterfall of your site and the fonts are loading way down below all the js stuff... http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.claireundgeorge.ch/ygS7Y3Cx < take a look at the timeline tab. This is probably why your font is taking so long to load

Comment: just a suggestion, It will much better if you had different colors in the title and description (contrast)...maybe color black the description :)

Comment: Just looked at the site in IE11. On first render I could see the problem but couldn't reproduce on multiple refreshes. After clearing the cache a reload caused the problem again. I'm assuming it is something to do with how quickly the font file is loaded - i.e whether widths are calculated using the default font or the custom font. I have run into the same prblem with my website with IE11 (and IE10). It  is OK in IE9 and all other browsers

Answer (score 0):

When you compare what is calculated in FireFox with what is calculated in IE you can see whats the bad boy here.

In IE the padding-bottom property of the h2 is 4px.
When i uncheck this property it looks fine for me.

I cannot upload pictures here due to the stupid reputation limit thing but i hope i descriped it good enough...

Comment: I can also uncheck the text-decoration-property and then it's looking good. This is (I presume) due to the fact that IE is re-rendering the elements. Changing the value for padding-bottom in the CSS does not change anything.

Comment: But with the fact, that your css isnt the same in every browser there could be more differences. I would compare all props and try and error until you find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I also have typotheque webfont + IE problem. My workaround for now is a bit dirty: I use jquery $(window).load to adjust element padding by 1px, and then IE redraws the font correctly.